# Cannot connect to a localhost SQL server database in UWP

Tags: asp.net, rest, api, asp.net-web-api, uwp

I have created a UWP application for testing purposes in which my purpose is to be able the application to connect to a ASP.NET Web API with a certificate for Indivual User Accounts, I've hosted the db into localhost, after ensuring the connection its correct and everything its ok I have deployed my UWP app, the problem is that when I execute a call to a method inside the Account controller (api/Account), the compiler throws me an exception which is the following:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=System.Net.Http

...

Inner Exception 1:
COMException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect
```

I have searched for the problem but there's not a "specific" or "correct" answer I've found, could anyone help me with this issue please?

if code snippets are required, let me know!

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Thanks Richard! I have viewed your solution, the problem is that seems that in the recent versions of Visual Studio, the option for disabling - enabling SSLS has dissapear, could you show me how to do it please?

Comment: First, your project needs to be a web project. Then, In the project `Properties` -> `Debug`, set Launch to `IIS Express`, and then SSL-related settings will appear at the bottom.